# Struggling to install sparse_dot_topn on Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I believe the package required Cython, so I ran the following command.

```
conda install -c anaconda cython
```

This installed correctly.

Then I ran the following command to download sparse_dot_topn:

```
conda install -c conda-forge sparse_dot_topn
```

I am seeing the following error:

Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

```
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                          

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - sparse_dot_topn -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']

Your python: python=3.7

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Package libcxx conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> libcxx[version='>=4.0.1']
sparse_dot_topn -> libcxx[version='>=9.0.0']
Package zlib conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
Package xz conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> xz[version='>=5.2.4,<6.0a0']
Package libffi conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> libffi[version='>=3.2.1,<4.0a0']
Package ncurses conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> ncurses[version='>=6.1,<7.0a0']
Package cython conflicts for:
sparse_dot_topn -> cython
Package openssl conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> openssl[version='>=1.0.2o,<1.0.3a|>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1b,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1c,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1d,<1.1.2a']
Package readline conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> readline[version='>=7.0,<8.0a0']
Package numpy conflicts for:
sparse_dot_topn -> numpy
Package scipy conflicts for:
sparse_dot_topn -> scipy
Package sqlite conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> sqlite[version='>=3.24.0,<4.0a0|>=3.25.2,<4.0a0|>=3.25.3,<4.0a0|>=3.26.0,<4.0a0|>=3.27.2,<4.0a0|>=3.29.0,<4.0a0|>=3.30.1,<4.0a0']
Package tk conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> tk[version='>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0']
Package pip conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> pip
```

Based on the error logs I think I need a lower version of python? Not 100% how to achieve this or if this is even the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create a new environment with the required python version. Its a problem with your python version, i tried this by making a new environment and it installed fine.

```
conda create --name your_env  "python>=3.6,<3.7"
```

Comment: where does the environment go? Do I need to put my files into this folder?

Comment: No, so you can always check your environments using this `conda info --envs` Then you can see the list of environments created and you just have to activate that environment. Then from anaconda terminal or whichever terminal you are working on, just type your command for installing `sparse_dot_topn`, anaconda will automatically install all the required dependencies for that package also.

Comment: I am getting the following error: Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

Comment: Even with the new environment?

Comment: Also which conda version do you have?

Comment: conda version : 4.8.2
    conda-build version : 3.18.11
         python version : 3.6.10.final.0